# Create Spraying Water from a Sprinkler

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am attempting to create water spraying from a fire sprinkler. I am not having the best time getting the water to look realistic. I have attempted [this tutorial](http://www.brighthub.com/multimedia/publishing/articles/106032.aspx) but I am not happy with the results. I have also attempted to use multiple rain and water brushes but they just do not have the effect I am looking for which is spraying water. (The rain brushes come the closest but not quite there.)

My question is how do you create realistic spraying water? (Think of a fire sprinkler spraying water)

I am using Photoshop CS6 and if there is a brush that will work great for this I would like to see it.

Comment: Use a photo and mask out the water.

Comment: Yep. Sometimes the most straightforward solution is the best one.

Comment: @Scott - I have toyed with the idea but assumed there was a more challenging option in life. =>   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you could also import a picture of spraying water and create your own brush in photoshop using this, then layer your results to get a nice effect. This also enables you to reuse your brush in the future.

Please refer to the following for how to create a brush:

http://www.bittbox.com/photoshop/how-to-make-a-photoshop-brush